# Where can I find how many roots the author needs to compose for each book of the Tenach

Tags: hebrew, tanach, grammar-dikduk, language, etymology

For example:  I am reading now the book of Joshua in Hebrew. It looks to me quite simple language. The author uses often the same terms.   Poetry and wisdom-litterature is much more complex. My question is: Where can I explore, how many roots the authors of the different books of Tanakh are using to compose their books.